# .htaccess - Rewrite all URLs in site structure

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following structure:

```
/public_html
    /FILES AND FOLDERS I MUST NOT TOUCH IN ANY WAY (not mine)
    /mysitefolder/ (this is mine)
        /images
        /js
        /index.php
        /someotherpage.php
```

Now, all the links in the pages inside **mysitefolder** are like this:

```
<a href="/someotherpage.php">A link</a>
<img src="/images/myimage.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/somescript.js"></script>
```

That is, all links were built using relative URLs beginning with "/" (i.e. assuming everything is in the server's public root).

What I need is, to fool (or "rewrite", if you will) these links into loading resources from "/mysitefolder/" instead of just "/". For example, the desired solution would turn the above links into:

```
<a href="/mysitefolder/someotherpage.php">A link</a>
<img src="/mysitefolder/images/myimage.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mysitefolder/js/somescript.js"></script>
```

How can I use the .htaccess file to accomplish this? I've been reading many threads, but nothing works for me and honestly I don't quite understand .htaccess.

Comment: Well, I solved my problem by creating a subdomain in the server (mysitefolder.thedomain.com). But I'd like to see if there's an alternative with .htaccess, anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I don't think you want to use static URL's, but just to get the URL's to work. As you said, the current URL's assume that the system starts in the root folder of the website. I would not recommend you to use htaccess, because its not working for this situation. You should edit the URL's in your html / php files to either

```
<a href="/mysitefolder/someotherpage.php">A link</a>
<img src="/mysitefolder/images/myimage.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mysitefolder/js/somescript.js"></script>
```

(if you want to link from the root) or

```
<a href="./someotherpage.php">A link</a>
<img src="./images/myimage.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/somescript.js"></script>
```

if you want a true relative link, that uses the current folder as beginning point.

In case the files in your root directory are not used, you can use a htaccess file to forward everything to mysitefolder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !mysitefolder [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysitefolder/$1 [L]
```

(not tested)